# Update database using java with one or more optional parameters

Tags: java, database, sql-update

I want to update a table with values from my program. However, I want to update only the values which have changes. The option I have is to write multiple PreparedStatement with update for each field, and execute the ones where field has changed. 
For e.g.

```
PreparedStatement update1 = connection.prepareStatement
    ("UPDATE items SET name = ? WHERE id = ?");

PreparedStatement update2 = connection.prepareStatement
    ("UPDATE items SET category = ? WHERE id = ?");

PreparedStatement update3 = connection.prepareStatement
    ("UPDATE items SET price = ? WHERE id = ?");
PreparedStatement update4 = connection.prepareStatement
    ("UPDATE items SET quantity = ? WHERE id = ?");
```

Can I write one PreparedStatement and update only what is required.
something which starts with

```
PreparedStatement update = connection.prepareStatement
    ("UPDATE items SET name = ?, category = ?, price = ?, quantity = ? WHERE id = ?");
...
...
update.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: No, but you can have a method generate the proper update statement from a Map or something that contains the input values.

Comment: Okay, you could do `SET name = COALESCE(?, name), ....` (and put in null when you don't want to update). I wouldn't, though.

Comment: Only column values can be set dynamically.  You'll have to use your first approach and use **if** statements to execute the PreparedStatement that needs executing.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks, thats the closest I have seen, for using only one update query